# mysql cast and convert does not change the type

Tags: mysql, string, symfony, casting, numbers

I am using symfony and mysql for my project.

The Database has a table call Articles where quantity and price are of **type** **double**.

I execute a

> SELECT quantity,price FROM articles

As I want to know the type of quantity and price:

> var_dump($lines);

It tells me quantity and price are **string**.
Same thing with gettype

> gettype($lines[0]['quantity'])

I have tried **CAST** and **CONVERT**, but it goes on beeing a string.

> SELECT convert(quantity,signed) from articles

> SELECT cast(quantity as signed) from articles

I need quantity to be a number, because JSON.strigify put "" to the strings, and the result is not what I need.

Comment: data comes back from MySQL as text, always

Comment: ok. so I understand that I have to cast all the lines in php or javascpript. Thanks

Comment: or: `select json_array(json_object('price',price), json_object('quantity',quantity)) from articles;`   (but it will still be text.... )